# PHP : curl login not redirecting to main domain

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to log in to Tumblr using Curl, Below curl post logins successfully ,But it redirects to mydomain.com/dashboard instead of tumblr.com/dashboard , How can i redirect to tumblr.com/dashboard  ? OR should i use GET curl to tumblr.com/dashboard using cookies ?

```
$url = 'https://www.tumblr.com/login';
$fields = array(
            'user[email]'=> $email,
            'user[password]'=>$pass,
            'tumblelog[name]'=> '',
            'user[age]'=> '',
            'recaptcha_public_key'=> urlencode($key),
            'recaptcha_response_field'=> '',
            'hk'=> urlencode($hk[1]), 
           'http_referer' => 'https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tumblr.com%2Flogin'
        );

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');
//open connection
$ch = curl_init();
//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

P.s : I got cookies stored successfully in cookie.txt , can i use that cookie to GET content of tumblr.com/dashboard

Comment: Have you considered using their [**API**](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2)?

Comment: nope ! i am trying to create blogs.API dont support that !

Comment: if u are logged in then cookies are set in your browser. then why are u using curl???

Comment: do u want to load in iframe??

Comment: No guys, he just wants to create autoblogs. Let him be! He's on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **For `$fields` use [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) FFS.** Why manually encode URLs? It's almost 2013.
2. **You need to visit the main page once.** So you can get cookied. With the same cookie jar and file load *tumblr.com/login* once to get your cookies up, then try to login and create the blog.
3. **You don't need to read the cookies from the jar.** cURL will keep track of them if you use the same cookie jar and file. So once you login, as long as you use the same cookie files, you'll be fine.
4. **Set** `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` **cURL options to false**. You don't need to verify their SSL certificates when you do such things.
5. Also **increase your** `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` and `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` **timeouts** to 30/60 seconds or even more in case the operation takes a while.

**Now try again.** Remeber, keep the same `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` and you'll be fine, if you do it right.